# is an Isometry onto?

Tags: real-analysis

I am confused with this, in many books I have found that an isometry is bijective. But 
I built a counterexample, an isometry from reals with the discrete metric to the interval $(0,1)$ with the discrete metric. It is an isometry from Reals to Reals which is not onto.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show your work?

Comment: I defined the map from $(R,d_1)$ to $(R,d_1)$, in this way:

$f(a)=0.ba_1a_2... 4$  (a has a decimal expansion, $a=b.a_1a_2...$)

it is an isometry, it is not onto. the Definition of discrete metric,:  $d(a,b)=1$ iff $a\ne b$

Comment: I have seen an isometry defined to be a map $f:(M,d)\to (N,\rho)$ such that $$d(x,y)=\rho(f(x),f(y))$$ for each pair $x,y\in M$. Note that from the fact that $d(x,y)=0\iff x=y$, an isometry is one-one. It needn't be onto, just "distance preserving".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the right shift operator $S : \ell^2(\mathbb{N}) \to \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, defined by
$$
 S(a_0,a_1,a_2,\dotsc) := (0,a_1,a_2,\dotsc).
$$
Then $S$ is an isometry in the Hilbert space sense, but in particular is an isometry in the topological sense for $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ as a metric space with metric
$$
 d(x,y) := \|x-y\| = \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left|x_k-y_k\right|^2}.
$$
However, $S(\ell^2(\mathbb{N})) = \{x \in \ell^2(\mathbb{N}) \mid x_0 = 0\} \subsetneq \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, so that $S$ is *not* onto.

That said, a linear isometry $S : V \to V$ for $V$ a *finite-dimensional* inner product space is injective and thus surjective, which might be what you have in the back of your mind?

Comment: Thank you, that what I had in the back of my mind

Answer (score 2):

The definition of isometry at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry) does not require the map to be onto. Perhaps you could supply a quote, with context, from one of these many books, so we could see what is actually happening here.